# Node Js what is the different between the coding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one question regarding Node js

Method 1:

```
app.post('/password-reset', resetPassword)

function resetPassword() {
// code here
}
```

vs

Method 2:

```
app.post('/password-reset',  function(req, res){
// code here
});
```

I understand that both are doing the same thing but why do we need method 1?

Is that any scenario that I must use method 1?

Comment: "*I understand that both are doing the same thing but why do we need method 1?*" You need it as much as option 2. In that, it's arbitrary which one you choose and there is very little reason to say that *generally* one is preferable over the other.

Comment: It's the same difference as `let foo = bar(); return baz + foo` and `return baz + bar()`. You don't *need* either one, except if it somehow makes more sense for you because… reasons.

Comment: If a teacher told you to use a particular method instead of another, then that method is better because it makes the teacher happier, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only practical difference is that method 1 leaves a `resetPassword` function in the scope of the module which can be reused later. That isn't likely to be useful for the endpoint function of a route which is likely to be assigned exactly once. You might want to export that function and unit test it though.

Everything else is code style preference. People would probably disagree on which is easier to read / maintain. Pick a style that suits you and the people you work with.